# Is there a way to include CASE WHEN or NVL in MERGE oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, nvl

I have a merge statement below and I want to add as a condition that if X_RECEIVED_ON_DT  is null, it will use the date in FULFILLED_ON_DT and PO_CLOSED_DT, which are columns in the TGT (target table) to populate the TGT.X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID column

```
 MERGE
/*+ PARALLEL(8) */
INTO W_PURCH_COST_F TGT USING
(SELECT
  /*+ PARALLEL(8) */
  cost.INTEGRATION_ID,
  cost.X_RECEIVED_ON_DT,
  cost.LOC_CURR_CODE,
  COALESCE(gaap.ROW_WID,0) X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID
FROM W_Purch_Cost_F_3955 cost
JOIN W_DAY_D wday
ON TRUNC(cost.X_RECEIVED_ON_DT)=TRUNC(wday.CALENDAR_DATE)
LEFT OUTER JOIN WC_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_G gaap
ON gaap.PERIOD               =wday.PER_NAME_ENT_PERIOD
AND cost.LOC_CURR_CODE       =gaap.FROM_CURCY_CD
) SRC ON (TGT.INTEGRATION_ID = SRC.INTEGRATION_ID AND TGT.DATASOURCE_NUM_ID = 310)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET TGT.X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID = SRC.X_GAAP_EXCH_RATE_WID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference `W_PURCH_COST_F` (alias `TGT`) in the *source* query, you'll have to include it into the `SRC`'s `FROM` clause.

It means that you'd have two `W_PURCH_COST_F` tables in this `MERGE` statement - one as the merge target (as you already have now), another as "source" used to join it with other table(s) in `SRC`. Then it is a simple task to use `NVL`, `CASE` or `DECODE` and do what you want.

Though, I don't quite understand how you'll use both `FULFILLED_ON_DT` and `PO_CLOSED_DT`, but I hope you know.

---

Example based on Scott's schema (as I don't have your tables):

This won't work - you can't reference `TGT` in `SRC`:

```
SQL> merge into emp e
  2  using (select distinct d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc
  3         from dept d
  4         where d.deptno = e.deptno                --> not allowed
  5        ) x
  6  on (e.deptno = x.deptno)
  7  when matched then update set e.ename = x.loc;
       where d.deptno = e.deptno
                        *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00904: "E"."DEPTNO": invalid identifier
```

But, if used in `SRC`'s `FROM` clause, it *works*:

```
SQL> merge into emp e
  2  using (select distinct d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc
  3         from dept d join emp a on a.deptno = d.deptno
  4        ) x
  5  on (e.deptno = x.deptno)
  6  when matched then update set e.ename = x.loc;

14 rows merged.

SQL>
```

---

Options you might want to consider are:

- Nested `NVL`: `nvl(x_received_on_dt, nvl(fulfilled_on_dt, po_closed_dt))`
- `coalesce` (returns first non-null value):

  ```
  coalesce(x_received_on_dt, fulfilled_on_dt, po_closed_dt, sysdate)
  ```

`coalesce` looks like a better choice to me.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot , Sorry it will use either FULFILLED_ON_DT or PO_CLOSED_DT, if FULFILLED_ON_DT is not null it will use that, if its null is will use PO_CLOSED_DT, else 0

Comment: OK, use nested NVLs. Though, you can't use 0 (a number) with DATE values because of inconsistent datatypes. Should be something else - a DATE value (e.g. SYSDATE or some *invalid* date, such as DATE '1000-01-01').

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, i got a missing keyword error. this is my select  NVL(CASE WHEN cost.X_RECEIVED_ON_DT IS NULL THEN SRC1.FULFILLED_ON_DT ELSE SRC1.PO_CLOSED_DT,0)

Comment: I edited my answer and added NVL and COALESCE examples; have a look.